# What is a gain from storing jws token in database

Tags: authorization, jwt

Recently someone mentioned he is using JWS token for authorisation, but JWS tokens received via API calls are validated against active ones stored in database. (**EDIT** he also checks signature).

In my opinion signature checking is just a waste of resources, but person who designed system insist on using JWS as he claims is more secure. 
Did I missed something? Is it right way to go?

Comment: Your question title is about gain from storing JWS in DB, but the body is asking about signature validation. Can you clarify really what you're trying to figure out?

Comment: @OmerIqbal i wonder is it any gain from storing jwt token on the backend in database. random generated token would do same job